# Issue with evaluating average of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, average

I am trying to display an array of test scores and above them, the average of those scores. Here is the code I am using:

```
var clickDisplayResults = function () {
  $("results").value = "";
  function calculate(scores) {
    var i = 0, sum = 0, len = scores.length;
    while (i < len) {
      sum = sum + scores[i++];
    };
    return sum / len;
};

var average = calculate(scores);
$("results").value = "The average score is: " + parseInt(average) + "\n";
$("results").value += "High Score: " + Math.max.apply(null, scores) + "\n";
$("results").value += "Low Score: " + Math.min.apply(null, scores) + "\n" + "\n";
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  $("results").value += names[i] + ", " + scores[i] + "\n";
};
```

When I do this, however, I get an average in a ridiculous range after adding a new score.

Here is the add score code:

```
var clickAddScore = function () {
  if ( $("name").value == "" || $("score").value < 0 || $("score").value > 100 || isNaN($("score").value) ) {
    alert("Please enter a valid name and score");
    $("name").value = "";
    $("score").value = "";
    return false;
  };
  else {
    names[names.length] = $("name").value;
    scores[scores.length] = $("score").value;
    $("name").value = "";
    $("score").value = "";
  };
};
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: value is a string, not a number, you need to convert it to a number

Comment: FYI: doing `$("name").value` over and over again is bad for performance. Store it into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with a string and treating it like a number

```js
console.log("100" + 100);
```

You need to convert the string to a number. You can use parseInt, parseFloat, Number, or Unary plus.

Your code is a bit inefficient since you keep accessing the DOM for the value so declare some variables. And your else statement was wrong.

```
var clickAddScore = function() {
  var studentName = $("name").value.trim();
  var score = Number($("score").value);
  if (studentName == "" || score < 0 || score > 100 || isNaN(score)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid name and score");
  } else {
    names.push(studentName);
    scores.push(score);
  }
  $("name").value = "";
  $("score").value = "";
}
```